# Copy data from one table to another using cursors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-cursor

i have a really large table (about 13 million rows) called Book. I want to set the primary key in a column of the Book table but as it is a very large table the server crashes during updating. It runs out of memory. So i created a BookTemp table, i set all primary keys in this empty table and then i want to insert the data from Book to BookTemp table. But if i do it at once the memory again runs out. So i thought to use cursors in order to insert 10,000 rows each time and then erase RAM but i am really new to cursors so in that point i would like your help.

I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: The server crashes? I *really* cannot imagine that. Maybe it becomes unresponsive, but it most certainly will not crash. Try switching your [database recovery model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx) to "Simple" before you add the primary key (do a full backup up-front to be safe). This way the operation will not be logged and should perform more quickly. Disabling any triggers is also a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a while loop to iterate over your temporary table. The example [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/04/sql-server-simple-example-of-while-loop-with-break-and-continue/) should get you started.

Or you could just modify this:

```
DECLARE @counter AS INT = 0;
DECLARE @batch_size AS INT = 10000;
WHILE (@counter < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM temp_table))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO the_table
  SELECT * FROM temp_table
  WHERE id BETWEEN @counter AND (@counter + @batch_size - 1);

  SET @counter = @counter + @batch_size;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

When executed following three commands will free up memory for SQL Server by cleaning up its cache.

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

However, it can be used in a on going operation, so please see blow query, after inserting each 10000 the memory is cleared by executing the above DBCC command.

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 1
DECLARE cur_Data_Transfer CURSOR FOR  -- Cursor declared
SELECT column1, column2  -- select desired columns
FROM Book 

OPEN cur_Data_Transfer  --Opening Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Data_Transfer INTO @column1, @column2  --Put values to variable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  -- Faching is success
BEGIN  
       INSERT INTO BookTemp (column1, column2) -- Inserting to temptable
            VALUES(@column1, @column2)
       IF @counter = 10000
       BEGIN    
        DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE -- Clear System Cache
        DBCC FREEPROCCACHE   -- Clear Proc Cache
        SET @counter = 0     -- Restarting counter
       END
       FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Data_Transfer INTO @column1, @column2
       SET @counter = @counter + 1
END  
CLOSE cur_Data_Transfer  -- Closing cursor
DEALLOCATE cur_Data_Transfer -- De-allocating
```